# JS function calling from the code behind Issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a JS function (Show alert box), and have a link button in ASP page, On click event from code behind for this link button I want to call this function and then redirect to certain page.

**ASP Code**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     function myFunction() {
         // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
         alert("document is ready!");
     }                   
 </script>
 <div>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnChangePassword" runat="server" Text="Change Passwrod" OnClick="lnkbtnChangePassword_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
 </div>
```

**C# Code**

```
 protected void lnkbtnChangePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "myFunction()", true);
     Response.Redirect("myPage.aspx");
 }
```

**Here when I click on the link button, it simply don't display the alert box/window and redirect to the page.**

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`LinkButton.ClientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `LinkButton.Click` event.

`Click` event is handled on server. When user clicks the button, page is posted back to server and code is executed on server side.

`ClientClick` event is really a name of JavaScript function which should be executed.

You should probably do something like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnChangePassword" runat="server" Text="Change Passwrod" OnClientClick="showMyAlertAndSubmit()"></asp:LinkButton>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showMyAlertAndSubmit(){
    alert("Your password is being changed");
    // submit your form
}
</script>
```

---

*Why your current code doesn't work*

You currently send script for showing a message, and redirect at the same time. This means that browser receives instructions to show a message and to redirect, and it redirects the user before showing the message. One approach could be to redirect from client side. For example:

```
 protected void lnkbtnChangePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "myFunction()", true);
 }
```

and on client side

```
function myFunction() {
    // show your message here
    // do other things you need
    // and then redirect here. Don't redirect from server side with Response.Redirect
    window.location = "http://myserver/myPage.aspx";
}
```

---

*Other options*

Since you need to first perform checks on server side before saving data and redirecting, you can use ajax to call server without performing postback.
Remove Click handler, and only use ClientClick:

```
function myFunction() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "myPage.aspx/MyCheckMethod",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
          ShowAlert();
          window.location = "http://myserver/mypage.aspx";
      }
    });
}
```

For more details [please check this tutorial](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but may later I want to add some code before displaying the message so I have to use in code behind.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? You want to click, and then do something on server side, and then go back to client side? In that case you will need a different approach. For example, making AJAX calls to server before submitting and redirecting.

Comment: Yes sir, that's what I want that when I click, and then do something on server side, and then go back to client side. Should I edit my question?

Comment: Ok, I understand. Then, can you redirect from client side? Don't redirect from server, but only register startup script, and then redirect from client side. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. Can you please explain more what you have add to your answer?  ShowAlert();
    SavePassword();
    window.location = "http://myserver/myPage.aspx";

Comment: You mean 1) don't redirect from `SERVER` side because user will be redirected before message is displayed, right?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I removed the comment and readding it here, fixed.Function names are only example. Important is 1) don't redirect from server side because user will be redirected before message is displayed 2) redirect from client side after showing the message.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

**ASP Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function myFunction() {
     // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
     alert("document is ready!");
    }                   
</script>
<div>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnChangePassword" runat="server" Text="Change Passwrod" OnClick="lnkbtnChangePassword_Click" OnClientClick="myFunction()" ></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

**C# Code**

```
protected void lnkbtnChangePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("myPage.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your javascript function to :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     function myFunction() {
         // alert will stop js execution
         alert("document is ready!");
         // then reload your page
         __doPostBack('pagename','parameter');
     }                   
 </script>
```

And call it from code-behind with this function :

```
protected void lnkbtnChangePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //do your job here
     //then call your js function
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "myFunction();", true);
 }
```

Comment: what's the `pagename` and the `parameter`?

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is waiting for JavaScript alert dialog to popup and then redirect to the page.
In order to do this you need to tell button to wait for JavaScript alert dialog to popup and then do the Server side work after.

ASPX:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function alertBeforeSubmit() {
           return alert('Document Ready');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button Text="Do" runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="return alertBeforeSubmit();" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

CS:

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```